# Is SSL communication with Greenplum database server different from normal SSL communication with a typical web server?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, greenplum

While enabling ssl in greenplum, it needs ONLY server.key(which is a  private key) & certificates to be present in the master data directory. 
What about public key and the session key? Why don't we need to provide these keys as well. 
If we don't provide these keys then how the ssl  communication will happen?

In General, ssl communication happens with the help of the public key and the private key( which is Asymmetric Encryption) for handshake and 
the session key will be used for actual data transfer between client and server(which is symmetric encryption).

Is it possible to have ssl communcation with only private key?.Does SSL communication with Greenplum database server is different from normal SSL communication with a typical web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public key is in the certificate. The session key is negotiated during the handshake. There is nothing different about this SSL server from any other SSL server in this respect.